How integrate @pinia-orm/axios to Nuxt 3 project so that i can use it with pini-orm? Official documention dosen't Nuxt example
The Official documention dosen't have Nuxt integration documentations or examples.
I tried creating a NUxt plugin with below code after installing all the plugins.
import { createORM } from 'pinia-orm';
import { setActivePinia } from 'pinia';
import { defineNuxtPlugin } from '#app';

import { piniaOrmPluginAxios } from '@pinia-orm/axios';

export default defineNuxtPlugin((nuxtApp) => {
  const piniaOrm = createORM();
  piniaOrm().use(piniaOrmPluginAxios);
  nuxtApp.$pinia.use(piniaOrm);
  setActivePinia(nuxtApp.$pinia);
});

I am getting an error that Axios is not registered.

import { Model, createORM, useRepo, type PiniaOrmPlugin } from 'pinia-orm';
import Brand from './Brand';
import { useAxiosRepo } from '@pinia-orm/axios';
import { createPiniaOrmAxios } from '@pinia-orm/axios';
import axios from 'axios';

    export class Product extends Model {
      static entity = 'products';
    
      static fields() {
        return {
          id: this.attr(null),
          //brand: this.belongsTo(Brand, 'brandId'),
          status: this.string(null),
          attribute_data: this.attr({}),
        };
      }
    
      declare id: number | null;
      //declare brand: typeof Brand;
      declare status: string;
      declare attribute_data: Object;
    }
    
    export const productRepository = useAxiosRepo(Product);

I would like some give me an example on how to integrate @pinia-orm/axios in nuxt 3.
